# How to fit 720p video on a 1080p container?

Tags: premiere

I am using Adobe Premier Pro to edit our short film and give some generic editing to it.

At the time of shoot we wanted a slow motion effect in a shot, so we shot at 720p at 60fps *(We had limitations, our camera doesn't supported 60fps at 1080p)*.

Now when post processing all the videos fit in the 1080 container but our slow motion video shows black blank space around them. How to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a clip scale to the resolution of the sequence by right-clicking on it and pressing **Set to frame size** (For older versions of Premiere, use **Scale to frame size**). To set this at the standard behaviour for new clips that aren't the same resolution as the sequence, go to **Preferences** → **General** and check **Default scale to frame size**.

However, keep in mind that upscaling a 720p video to 1080p won't yield you any more quality, worse case, it will look worse. Also, exporting to 1080p when your video is actually only 720p is kind of tricking the viewer. If you upload an upscaled video to Youtube and flag it as 'Full HD', I will so downvote your video ... So if your source material is shot in 720p, I would highly recommend you export to 720p.

Comment: :( Then I will have to downscale all the remaining clips to 720p.

Comment: Well it depends on how much of your project is shot in 1080p. If most of it is 1080p and you have like one scene that's in 720p, it's maybe better to export to 1080p ... generally, I would recommend shooting everything with the same settings, because whenever you're don't you're gonna face exactly that problem. If the camera doesn't support 1080p@60fps, a case could be made to shoot the entire project in 720p@60fps as opposed to 1080p@30fps (or whatever). Though I guess that's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Upscaling would be preferred in most cases if its just one shot.
Quite a few productions do ultra slow-mo scenes with a GoPro and adjust the GoPro footage to the rest.